# Ideal method to virtually connect two ports transparently in a switch

Tags: networking, switch, local-area-network, wide-area-network

I have an Aruba 2930F 48G PoE+ 4SFP+ switch. It has mostly default configurations, therefore all ports act as if it is transparent.

The router is a Belkin RT1800 running OpenWRT 23.05.2.

The internet connection is FTTP through an ONT, and its Ethernet port is connected directly to the Internet WAN port on the router. The router is then connecting via PPPoE to get a WAN address. The router has one of its LAN ports connected to the switch.

All is working as normal, and as expected. All devices connected to the switch get internet access through the router.

---

I'd like the ONT to be powered through PoE from the Switch, and I'd like the router to be physically located away from the rack. In theory I'd like to be able to connect the ONT to the Switch, and the router's internet port to the Switch, and have the two ports they're connected to act transparently to each other, and logically separated from the LAN.

I figured setting up a VLAN for this may be the way, however the VLAN configuration asks for a gateway which I don't believe I can provide, and it's asking for an IP address which I also can't provide.

The switch supports trunking too, however trunking the two ports together doesn't seem to allow the communication from the router to the ONT to login.

What's the ideal method to make this happen? I'd like to bind two physical ports on the switch together, and have their traffic be transparent to each other, and completely separated from all other ports on the switch.

---

The response below has not helped at all. The documentation they link to isn't valid for my Switch, and a lot of the stages mentioned don't exist.

I have however attempted the Tagged vs Untagged methods they mentioned, to no avail. Port 1 and Port 48 are the ports I wish to use for this WAN tunnel. Setting these two ports to Tagged doesn't allow communication, as in PPPoE fails to connect. Setting all other ports to Tagged means that my entire LAN cannot reach anything else (including my computing reaching the Switch's WebUI, I had to revert it through serial port).

The reply below mentions not creating a VLAN interface, but to use tagged and untagged ports. This isn't working out as expected. Below are some images of my options from the WebUI.

[Image of Aruba Switch WebUI VLAN Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mp4wR.png)

I do however notice that I do get a gateway address from my router after connection is made. Perhaps this could be used as the gateway to a separate VLAN?

[Image of OpenWRT Router Network Upstreams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdOQk.png)

I'm still at a loss to a solution to this, and I don't believe it's an impossible thing to be able to do. I don't believe this question is a duplicate to the one mentioned above, nor is it answered.

Answer (score 1):

> I figured setting up a VLAN for this may be the way, however the VLAN configuration asks for a gateway which I don't believe I can provide, and it's asking for an IP address which I also can't provide.

VLAN *is* the correct thing. But you don't want a VLAN *interface*, you want to configure your ports to be untagged members of a VLAN. A VLAN interface is only needed if you want to reach the switch management on that VLAN, or you want the switch to have L3 functionality.

From the [Documentation](https://www.arubanetworks.com/techdocs/ArubaOS_62_Web_Help/Content/ArubaFrameStyles/Network_Parameters/Configuring_VLANs.htm):

> 1. Navigate to the Configuration > Network > VLANs page.
> 2. Click Add a VLAN to create a new VLAN. (To edit an existing VLAN click Edit for the VLAN entry.) See Creating Bulk VLANs In the WebUI to create a range of VLANs.
> 3. In the VLAN ID field, enter a valid VLAN ID. (Valid values are from 1 to 4094, inclusive).
> 4. To add physical ports to the VLAN, select Port. To associate the VLAN with specific port-channels, select Port-Channel.
> 5. (Optional) Click the Wired AAA Profile drop-down list to assign an AAA profile to a VLAN. This wired AAA profile enables role-based access for wired clients connected to an untrusted VLAN or port on the controller.
>    Note that this profile will only take effect if the VLAN or port on the controller is untrusted. If you do not assign an wired AAA profile to the VLAN, the global wired AAA profile applies to traffic from untrusted wired ports.
> 6. If you selected Port in step 4, select the ports you want to associate with the VLAN from the Port Selection window.
>    -or-
>    If you selected Port-Channel in step 4, click the Port-Channel ID drop-down list, select the specific channel number you want to associate with the VLAN, then select the ports from the Port Selection window.
> 7. Click Apply.